# laravel two columns that represent one table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Okay so I'm building a soccer manager web app. I have a teams table:

```
------------------
| id  | name      |                 
------------------
| 1   | Barcelona |
------------------
| 2   | Madrid    |
------------------
```

I also have a season_games table here is a slimmed down version:

```
------------------------------------------
| id  | season_id | away_team | home_team |                       
------------------------------------------
| 1   |     1     |    1      |     2     |
------------------------------------------
| 2   |     1     |    2      |     1     |
-------------------------------------------
```

This is used for retriving the teams upcoming games something like this in the html:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Season Name</th>
                <th>Home Team</th>
                <th>Away Team</th>
                <th>Score</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($all_games as $game)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ $game->seasons->name }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $game->home_team }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $game->away_team }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $game->home_score . " x " . $game->away_score}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $game->game_date }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Okay so what I'm trying to do is make it so both away_team AND home_team are related to the teams table. So that in me views I don't need to run a getNameFromId function since obviously there are hundreds of games which means hundreds of sql queries. What would be an efficient way to go about this?

Comment: What are you using the names for?

Comment: @eluong to show the teams fixtures

Comment: Set up two `hasOne()` relations between the SeasonGames model and the Teams model, one for home team and one for the away team; and two `hasMany()` relations between the Teams model and the SeasonGames model, one for home games, the other for away games

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you I was trying to find out if that was possible i guess i should of just done it and thats the best reseach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join would be great since you don't have to do trivial queries.
Assume you have model set up like:
Team
Game
I would do it like this with raw statement:

```
Game::join('teams AS t1', 't1.id', '=', 'matches.away_team')
->join('teams AS t2', 't2.id', '=', 'matches.home_team')
->select('matches.id', 't1.name', 't2.name')
->get();
```

One way to reduce queries on server side is just to return to client side all the ids that showed up in the matches and return those rows in your teams table to client side and decode there.
Please give me feedback.
It is my first time writing a response.